# castling notation detecting both expressions

Tags: java, regex

Hi guys I have problem getting the regex castling notation right.

```
O-O - King
O-O-O - Queen
```

I have the following code

```
Pattern castlingKPattern = Pattern.compile("O-O");
Matcher castlingKMatch = castlingKPattern.matcher(pgn);

Pattern castlingQPattern = Pattern.compile("O-O-O");
Matcher castlingQMatch = castlingQPattern.matcher(pgn);

if (castlingKMatch.find()){

        System.out.println("Castling King: "+ pgn);

}       
}else if (castlingQMatch.find()){

        System.out.println("Castling Queen: "+ pgn);
}
```

But the following code keeps on going to the first if not to the second if statement. Even if I change the input to O-O-O which is supposed to go to CastlingQMatch or second if.
Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: Can we see example of input in `pgn`?

Comment: Why not just `if ("O-O".equals(pgn))` and `if ("O-O-O".equals(pgn))` respectively?

Comment: The first expression exactly includes the second. Check for queen's side first, then king's side.

Comment: Because there are other moves made by chess such as this one e4e5, e4xd5, O-O-O, etc

Comment: Thanks chrylis your suggestion works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict the first regex to this:

```
"(?<!O-)O-O(?!-O)"
```

- `(?!-O)` is negative lookahead that means fail the match if `-O` is next
- `(?!<O-)` is negative lookbehind that means fail the match if `O-` is preceding text

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE0pY4/1)

Comment: Thanks anubhava your solution works but I need to re-order my if else statement to detect first the queen then the king as suggested by @chrylis